# If possible, how to successfully implement nested Media Queries

Tags: sass, media-queries

Currently, i have two media queries which are not too different outside of a couple settings.

Current:

```
@media screen and (min-width:501px){
    div {
        &.footer-container {
            text-align:center;

            ul {
                li {
                    display:inline;

                    &.divider {
                        border-right: solid 1px black;
                        border-left:solid 1px black;
                        margin-right:4px;
                        margin-left:4px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:500px){
    div {
        &.footer-container {
            ul {
                li {
                    &.divider {
                        border-top:solid 1px black ;
                        border-bottom: solid 1px black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see both queries are looking at the `screen`.  I dont expect to be able to do a crazy nested statement for every section of the media query but would be nice if i could do something that makes the scss readible in context, instead of putting the media-queries at the bottom of my Site.scss file (this does all the inclusions and such).

Looking to do something similar to, maybe not exactly like.  My VS2012 implementation of SCSS doesn't like this hence why i am asking:

```
@media screen {
    & and (min-width: 501px){

    }

    & and (max-width: 500px){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just nest them like you nest them in any other selector:

```
@media screen {
    @media (min-width: 501px) {

    }

    @media (max-width: 500px) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This will at least get me to where i can nest the models correctly without overloading lines ;) I was reading on sass about doing something like this within the selected object and at parsing time it pulls the media query declarations into one group.  I may have read more into it but thats what i got out of it.